# Deleting row based off cell content with loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following:

```
For i = 1 To 400:
    If Cells(i, 7) = "Client" Then
    Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

The problem is say that I have `Client` in both Cells(10,7) and Cells(11,7). 
Once row(10) is deleted row(11) becomes the new row (10) and I'm on my way to looking for `Client` in row(11) and I won't find it (unless client was in row(12) from the start) so I end up with a lot of rows not deleted.

Comment: Consider: Selecting all the rows to delete then issuing delete once; outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting or deleting rows in excel sheet should be done from the last line.

```
For i = 400 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 7) = "Client" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decrement the variable i inside the if condition, does it work.

Example:

```
For i = 1 To 400
    If Cells(i, 7) = "Client" Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        i = i – 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Careful, `For i = 1 To 400:` doesn't need "**:**"  . Makes me think Python